# Linux+Docker - How to run host's apps from inside Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, system-administration

I want to know if Docker can run apps installed in host in the container so that I dont need to install the app on each images which wastes the hard disk space.

I know Linux is different since it requires dependencies and packages locally but I wonder if it is possible to use it like in Windows VM. 
In Windows Hyper-V, I did this by sharing the network folder containing portable apps with the container and run apps from inside the Windows VM.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can link a directory on your host containing the executables into your container. Then it will be accessible in the container. To do so, you can use [VOLUMES -- Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume) and mount a host directory (here: /tmp/foo) into your container (here: /foo) and execute a script called foo.sh in your container's location /foo/foo.sh:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
echo -e "#\!/bin/sh\n\necho foo" > /tmp/foo/foo.sh

docker run --rm -v /tmp/foo:/foo alpine sh /foo/foo.sh
=> foo
```

The same way, you can add binaries from your host to your container... But I do not think that this is intended and should be used, because a container should work as a standalone, isolated "lightweight-VM". You add an unnecessary dependency to your host machine to it, which seems not to be an elegant solution.

Comment: @n20 I am going to use this to automate a process on an existing machine to create an API for a piece of existing software.  The liscence is tied to the machine so it makes no sense to try and bundle the executeable in a container.